# Save web page in cache to load in webview

Tags: android, caching, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to save in cache some web pages (not from the same website) using okhttp. My idea is to save about 20-30 web pages in cache (this task will be executed by a IntentService) and then, once the user request to view a web page, the app should check if it's in the cache (the webpage will be loaded from internet if not in cache of course).

Downloading the html using okhttp is pretty easy but now I am wondering how and if I should save CSS and how can the webviewclient should load the page from the cache.

In my service I wrote the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> urls = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(MyFragment.RESULTS_LIST);

    File cacheDir = new File(getCacheDir().getPath());
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    for (String url : urls) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String output = response.body().string();

                    Log.d(TAG, output);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error");
                }

                response.body().close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can see, in debug, that the Cache object is populated but I cannot check in my device if the cache is actually written in it so I don't know if the WebView is trying to read from the cache or not.

Comment: `Loading the html using okhttp is pretty easy`?  I think that you mean that downloading html with okhttp is pretty easy.  `how can the webviewclient should load the page from the cache`. The WebView can do that with `.loadUrl()`. If the htmll's refer to css pages than you should download them too. Okhttp can download them. What type of cache do you have in mind?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant downloading html is pretty easy. I am thinking to cache in the internal memory maybe? Even using cacheDir but not sure if it makes sense there. I don't need to keep the website forever, just the time that app is used by the user and once he exits the app they can be deleted. If I download html and css in one folder, how can I load them using .loadUrl() in the WebView?

Comment: .loadUrl( "file://" + absolutePath );